# UITableView have space at right side and bottom on viewController in IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, space

I created viewController, then put TableView inside it. It look ok at storyboard. But after run, it have space at right side and bottom side. I already uncheck `Adjust scroll view Insets` at viewController. I also put code

```
self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(108, 0, 0, 0)
```

But still can't solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you haven't give it any constraint yet, please read more tutorial on how to use storyboard

Comment: share this tableview's storyboard constraint list

Comment: give constraint for table view ?

Answer (score 1):

Hello give constraint for table view :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your viewcontroller's top bar is `Translucent Navigation Bar`
or not and then set tableview constraint(leading, trailing, top and bottom) as set in given image.

[image]